# Angular 2 Directive For Required Fields Not Working

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Am creating Angular 2 Directive for required fields which is not Working as Expected

Functions I need to achieve is, if that directive is included in template input as an attribute it must check the field is empty or not, if empty it must throw an error

My Code

```
import {Directive, Attribute, forwardRef} from '@angular/core';
import {NG_VALIDATORS,AbstractControl,Validator} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({

selector : '[requiredValidators][formControlName],[requiredValidators][formControl],[requiredValidators][ngModel]',
providers : [
    {provide:NG_VALIDATORS,useExisting:forwardRef(()=>requiredValidations),multi :true}
]

})

export class requiredValidations implements Validator {
constructor(@Attribute('requiredValidators')public requiredValidators:string){}
validate(c:AbstractControl):{[key: string]:any}{
let inputValue = c.value;
if(inputValue == "" || inputValue == null){

}
return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the required directive in the documentation? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Comment: @echonax I need to create a required validation directive with messages this is my requirement

Comment: Did you check the link I've linked? It gives a message if the input is empty. Doesn't it work for your case?

Comment: @echonax I need that but want to create with message in the dircetive itself